# How to use loop in function on php

Tags: php, html

I want to generate a random password to use a function and use a loop on function.The for loop doesn't work on it.First number print on it.How can I solve it.
My PHP code is

```
    <?php
$password="";
if (isset($_POST['btn'])){
    function myPassword($data){
        $password="";
        $given_length=$data['given_length'];
        $value=array('#','A','p','Q','1','.',"%",'$','9','Z','z','5');
        for ($i=1;$i<$given_length;$i++){
            $index=rand(0,10);
            $password=$value[$index];
        }
        return $password;
    }
    $password=myPassword($_POST);

}
?>
```

And my html code is

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter a password length</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="given_length"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Your password is</td>
            <td><?php echo $password; ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btn"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</form>
```

Comment: What does `$data` contain?

Comment: You're overwriting the result in every loop with `$password=$value[$index];`. You probably want something like `$password.=$value[$index];`

Comment: You are defining a function but you never run it. Just move your code out of the function definition

Comment: Thanks.I do not concate with result $password.=value[$index.].Instead of that I do that $password=$value[$index];That means the last result print on the output.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the php

```
 <?php
$password="";
if (isset($_POST['btn'])){
    function myPassword($data){
        $password="";
        $given_length=$data['given_length'];
        $value=array('#','A','p','Q','1','.',"%",'$','9','Z','z','5');
        for ($i=1;$i<$given_length;$i++){
            $index=rand(0,10);
            $password . =$value[$index];
        }
        return $password;
    }
    $password=myPassword($_POST);

}
?>
```

`$password .=$value[$index];` will append the values to the password variable while `$password =$value[$index];` just deletes the previous entry

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is on this line:

```
 $password=$value[$index]
```

This will re assign the $password to be a new character everytime you complete a loop. Instead, you should do this:

```
$password= $password . $value[$index]
```

Comment: Yes.That,s right.Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Correct this line:

```
$password .= $value[$index];
```